# Undefined index when returning database results in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to transfer data over from a Wordpress database into a Codeigniter project. I have a model method that returns a single value, but I keep getting the following:

> Message: Undefined index: meta_value
>
> Filename: models/transfer_model.php

Here's the model:

```
 public function get_meta($post_id, $key)
    {
        $this->db->select('meta_value');
        $this->db->from('wp_postmeta');
        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->where('meta_key', $key);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->row_array();

        return $row['meta_value'];
    }
```

If I `print_r($row);`, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [meta_value] => The Data
)
```

How can I stop it from returning this error?

Comment: That's pretty strange...Is this the actual code you're using? Does the error refer to the same line of code of your return or it is somewhere else?

Comment: ya it's the same line as the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where there record fetched you are getting return when there is no record fetched with query then there will be nothing means your row is empty to avoid this use key_exists or array_key_exists have look on php doc

[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
public function get_meta($post_id, $key)
    {
        $this->db->select('meta_value');
        $this->db->from('wp_postmeta');
        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->where('meta_key', $key);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->row_array();

        $return = '';
        if(key_exists('meta_value',$row))
         $return = $row['meta_value'];

        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the record DOES exist as print_r shows, but yet it's still showing that error.

Comment: then try just $row = $query->row(); and return $row->meta_value

Answer (score 0):

What if you use an integer index?

```
$row = $query->row_array();
return $row[0];
```